# scrolling gets disabled after setContentOffset:animated:, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I want to programmatically scroll a specific amount of pixels. Changing the content offset inside the scrollViewDidScroll method i can do this but when it stops at the desired point it stops scrolling, i cant make it scroll in any direction.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x) < 0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(-141, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

Also, what i want to do is to be able to scroll horizontally to left and right as much as i want, any ideas of how can i achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`

Comment: That makes the job but the problem is that once i scrolled to where i want to the user interaction gets disabled, if i try to scroll by dragging i can't.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to have both of these properties set to true.

```
       self.tableView.bounces = true;
       self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true;
```